# Displaying Directus data inside sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit, directus

I am testing out directus where I had a site set up using appwrite and I want to check the differences. on my sveltekit side I am failing to get the data in like the way i had in appwrite:

```
<script context="module">
import { Directus } from '@directus/sdk';

const directus = new Directus('http://localhost:8055');

async function publicData() {
    // GET DATA

    // We don't need to authenticate if the public role has access to some_public_collection.
    const publicData = await directus.items('Home_Page').readByQuery({ sort: ['id'] });

    // console.log(publicData.data);
}

  </script>
  
  <script>
    export let publicData;
    console.log(publicData);
  </script>
  
  <!-- {#each publicData as post}
    <h1> {post.title} </h1>
    <h3> {post.excerpt} </h3>
  {/each} -->
```

not sure what I am missing. On the directus side I have made a singleton and filled out the data and made it viewable by the public role. Thought I would be able to see API stream but alas I am missing something

I have been going through documentation but the articles for sveltekit and directus

Comment: Did you check the browser console? What errors does it show?

Comment: GET http://localhost:5173/images/stock/photo-1534528741775-53994a69daeb.jpg 404 (Not Found)
news:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
client.js?t=1677014673855&v=5adbe29f:1862 <Page> was created without expected prop 'publicData' <<< this is what  get